# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): stoi

Tags: c++, string

Why I am getting this error on input `1534236469` in the below code?

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'  what():  stoi

```
int reverse(int x) {
    string s = to_string(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size() / 2; i++) {
        swap(s[i], s[s.size() - 1 - i]);
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        x = -stoi(s);
    } else {
        x = stoi(s);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Consider the possible case with `s.size()` is 0.

Comment: you can use `std::reverse` to reverse a string

Answer (score 6):

When you reverse `1534236469` you get `9646324351`, that does not fit an `int`, the maximum value for an `int`, in most cases, is `2147483647`.

Use `stoll` instead of `stoi` and use `long long` instead of `int` for `x` variable type, otherwise the assignment will overflow and cause [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 1):

You've got two questions: why is `terminate()` being called, and why is `out_of_range()` being thrown?

`terminate()` is being called, per the standard, because you don't have an exception handler (you didn't surround your call to `reverse` with `try...catch`).

`out_of_range()` is being thrown by `stoi` because the value it's given is out of range for an `int`.  `9646324351`, as @anastaciu points out, is outside the range of an `int` on your machine.

Comment: gdb shows it happening here: `(std::string) $0 = "9646324351"`, which, as @anastaciu points out, is outside the range of an `int`. @ChrisMM, you're right; I mentioned the wrong direct cause in my first version.